# Adding a COM interface to an existing application (EXE)

Tags: com, out-of-process

I intend to add a COM interface to an existing application (which, by the way, is written in C++ using Win32). I have some experience *using* COM objects, so I know the basic COM concepts of interfaces, etc., but this is the first time I'm actually implementing a component.

Ultimately I want to be able to use the COM interface to automate my application from scripts such as VB. I understand that there are two steps:

1. My application must act as an out-of-process server (i.e. I have to use MIDL and generate code for a proxy DLL and a stub DLL).
2. Once I have the server I can add automation capabilities by implementing the IDispatch interface.

Since the server-in-an-EXE thing with MIDL and what not is already a bit steep, I wanted to get a grasp on all that first before moving on to IDispatch.

I am reading the book "Inside COM" by Dale Rogerson and have completed the chapter on servers in EXEs (the following chapter will cover Automation).

The "Servers in EXEs" chapter provides example code that implements a server and a client. But it is necessary to start the server manually. This confuses me. Obviously, when my application (= server) is used by a client process, this extra manual step should not be necessary. Is there no mechanism to start the server automatically? **Or is automation necessary to achieve that?** At the moment, the prospect of having to start my server manually (once I even have one) makes me doubt I am moving in the right direction.

Hopefully someone with more knowledge of this can see what information I'm missing and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, COM servers are not normally started by hand.  Not sure why the book proposed it, possibly because it wanted to avoid talking about the registry keys you need to allow COM to automatically start the EXE.  It isn't otherwise very complicated, you register the Application coclass of your app with the LocalServer32 key value giving the path to the EXE.

It is however not completely uncommon, especially with an existing program.  One design decision to make is whether you let the client code completely control your program.  Or if your program already has an existing user interface but you also want to expose services to other code.  In the latter case it makes sense to let the user start the app by hand, like she'd normally does.

Answer (score 1):

When your application is registered as `LocalServer32`, it will be invoked with the commandline specified there if no running process has registered a factory object for your CLSID yet.

This way, you can get the best of both worlds -- if the application is running already, this instance can provide the server side, and if it isn't, it will be started.

Automation is completely orthogonal to that -- your component becomes Automation compatible by implementing `IDispatch`.